# React State order of operations

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-ref

Im going through this React course and came upon this issue setting state.  I have two components `TimerChallenge`

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ResultModal from "./ResultModal";

export default function TimerChallenge({ title, targetTime }) {
  const timer = useRef();
  const dialog = useRef();

  const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(targetTime * 1000);
  const timerIsActive = timeRemaining > 0 && timeRemaining < targetTime;

  if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    setTimeRemaining(targetTime * 1000);
    dialog.current.open();
  }

  function handleStart() {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeRemaining((prevTimeRemaining) => prevTimeRemaining - 10);
    }, 10);
  }

  function handleStop() {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    dialog.current.open();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ResultModal ref={dialog} targetTime={targetTime} remainingTime={timeRemaining}/>
      <section className="challenge">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p className="challenge-time">
          {targetTime} second{targetTime > 1 ? "s" : ""}
        </p>
        <p>
          <button onClick={timerIsActive ? handleStop : handleStart}>
            {timerIsActive ? "Stop" : "Start"} Challenge
          </button>
        </p>
        <p className={timerIsActive ? "active" : undefined}>
          {timerIsActive ? "Timer is running..." : "Timer inactive"}
        </p>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

and `ResultModal`

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const ResultModal = forwardRef(function (
  { targetTime, remainingTime, onReset },
  ref
) {
  const dialog = useRef();

  const userLost = remainingTime <= 0;
  const formatttedRemainingTime = (remainingTime / 1000).toFixed(2);
  const score = Math.round((1 - remainingTime / (targetTime * 1000)) * 100);

  // Define properties and methods on this component from outside this compoent
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      open() {
        dialog.current.showModal();
      },
    };
  });

  return createPortal(
    <dialog ref={dialog} className="result-modal">
      {userLost && <h2>You lost</h2>}
      {!userLost && <h2> Your score: {score}</h2>}
      <p>
        The target time was <strong>{targetTime} seconds.</strong>
      </p>
      <p>
        You stopped the timer with{" "}
        <strong>{formatttedRemainingTime} seconds left.</strong>
      </p>
      <form method="dialog" onSubmit={onReset} onClose={onReset}>
        <button>Close</button>
      </form>
    </dialog>,
    document.getElementById("modal")
  );
});

export default ResultModal;
```

This app is like a game where you press a button to start a timer and then press it again as close as you can to  a second.

What happens is that if it takes a user longer than 1 sec to press the button again, a modal should pop up with the text "You lose...", however instead of printing that out it prints out the winning prompt
[image]

In the lecture they say the bug is with these lines within `TimerChallenge`

```
  if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    setTimeRemaining(targetTime * 1000);
    dialog.current.open();
  }
```

in that we are resetting the time state.

I understand that React doesnt update state instantly and instead does it asynchronously, but for this example what are the order of operations in which the state value is updated and the component is rerendered ?
Or if we are rerending the component because the state was updated, how are we still opening the modal??